# Pandas, in lambda function get TypeError: len() of unsized object

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, CompConfig:

```
    days    recent_days     min_conf_level_firs_iteration     min_user_active_days  
0    1            7                 0.8                        10
```

and local_users:

```
  clienthostid  score   siduser
0       1        1728      1
1       1        1331      2
3       1        125       3
4       1        216       4
2       3        1000      5
5       3        512       6
```

Per clienthostid, I want get all the siduser the their score divided by SumOfScores is greater then min_conf_level_firs_iteration.

I do:

```
min_conf_level_firs_iteration = \
    CompConfig.loc[0, 'min_conf_level_firs_iteration'].astype(float)

local_users.groupby(
    ['clienthostid'], sort=False
)['score'].apply(
    lambda x: min_conf_level_firs_iteration > (x / local_users['score'].sum()))
```

and I get the error:

> if len(self) != len(other): TypeError: len() of unsized object

but if I try it with 0.8 it works:

```
local_users.groupby(['clienthostid'], sort=False)['score'].apply(lambda x: 0.8 > (x / local_users['score'].sum()))
```

Is it because of the way I get min_conf_level_firs_iteration? I thought I get it as const number...
I'm a very new beginner in Python and Pandas, so sorry if the question a bit obvious

Thank you

Comment: I didn't get an error when running this.